# Vue js 2 : How to filter array without mutation?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, filter, vuejs2

I have a very simple Laravel /Vue js website, I have a list of product which I would like to filter.

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#main-content',
data: {
    forfaits: window.forfaits,
},
methods: {
   filterData: function (val) {
        console.log(val)
        this.forfaits = this.forfaits.filter(item => {
          return item.internet >=val[0] && item.internet <= val[1] ;
      });
      return this.forfaits;
      
  }
```

**HTML**

```
 <div class="product-item offre" v-for="forfait in forfaits">
 .....
 ..... 
 .....
```

In this case it works but the original product array (forfaits) is mutated.
How can I filter without mutating the original value?

Comment: Use a computed property which calculates a filtered array.

Comment: If you don't want to change `this.forfaits`, why are you setting `this.forfaits`?

Comment: Like @wostex suggested, use computed properties. If you insist on doing it with a method, return the filtered array directly instead of assigning it to any variable.

Comment: @wostex can you tel me more about how to implement this solution ?

Comment: @SLaks i dont know how to do it defferently

Comment: How to do what? Set a different field?

Comment: Nothing happen when i use return in place setting this.forfaits

Comment: @SLaks if i use a computed property, then how to desplay the list before sorting ?

Comment: It sounds like you want a computed property which always returns the items you want to display (either filtered or not)

Comment: Exactlly, actually i'am getting the $forfaits variable from php Laravel, then i put it on my Vue's data object, and here i would like to filter the products without mutation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to have two properties:

1. A source-of-truth property with all unfiltered items, which is never consumed by the UI.
2. A computer property with the actual list to display, which at any point will return the complete list if there is no filter, or a filtered list if there is a filter.  This is what you bind the UI to.

You don't need any methods; the computed property will automatically update as the filter changes.